# What's the black knob near the oil pan?

Tags: oil, leak, oil-leak, oil-pan

What's this black knob near the oil pan under my car (2007 Hyundai Santa Fe AWD)?

Oil seems to be leaking from or near it (black liquid, I assume it's oil), trying to troubleshoot first leak.

[image]

Comment: I think that's the oil filter cartridge.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your engine is the 2.7 litre, then that is the oil filter.

You can see this in [this video detailing how to do an oil change on the 2.7 litre](https://youtu.be/r02mHvODzKA?si=Wev3PxJ71FbCwxvk&t=264) engine.

The oil filter may just need tightening a little, or probably best replace the filter.  The filter shouldn't be overtightened however.  Best to read the instructions on correct tightening, [like in this example video.](https://youtu.be/58X47dYVv_Q?si=CWxwdcCn89Yr6QkL&t=5)

Best to get this attended to soon, since the oil filter may be working loose.  If it does unscrew, it will cause a very quick dump of all of your oil which would be catastrophic for your engine.